# Database restore problem trigger and stored procedure (Mysql / Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We are using single source with multiple database concept. I am trying to restore db(.sql file) to client database, all tables restore fine except trigger and stored procedure.

### Our view

[image]

### Controller

```
public function import_database(){ 
$data = $this->input->post();
        if(!empty($data)) 
            {
            $config_app = array(
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => $data['cmp_db_name'],
            'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => TRUE
            );
            $this->db =$this->load->database($config_app,TRUE); // open client database connection
                        $filename=$_FILES["database"]["tmp_name"];      
                        $templine = '';
$lines = file($filename);
 foreach ($lines as $line)
{
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
continue;
$templine .= $line;
if (substr(trim($line), -1) == ';')
{
$this->db->query($templine);
$templine = '';
}
}
}
}
```

I got the following error:

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE audt_pro (IN coumn_n' at line 1 DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost` PROCEDURE audt_pro (IN coumn_nm TEXT, IN deleted_id TEXT, IN tbl_nm VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN DECLARE qry text;

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Cool story bro. Thanks for sharing the status report. For MySQL stored programs that include a semicolon character, we need to use a statement delimiter other than a semicolon when we execute e.g. a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. (Looks the the code in the question would chop off a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement at the first semicolon character it encountered.

Comment: got error : Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `audt_pro` (IN `coumn_n' at line 1

DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `audt_pro` (IN `coumn_nm` TEXT, IN `deleted_id` TEXT, IN `tbl_nm` VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN DECLARE qry text;

Comment: post the contents off the sql file here, Remove inserts with user sensitive data first ofcource before pasting.